# Return failure in Azure functions

Tags: azure-functions, azure-function-app

I can see more people suggest just to throw an exception when something goes wrong. But this can result in the worker process to restart destroying all functions running in the azure function. So how do you state this function failed, show failed and start retry mechanism.

```
[FunctionName("RunProcessSite")]
public static void Run([TimerTrigger("0 0 1 * * *",RunOnStartup = false)]TimerInfo myTimer, TraceWriter log)
{
        try
        {
            var spoMaintainServiceRun = new SPOMaintainServiceRun();
            spoMaintainServiceRun.Run(configuration, logger);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            log.Error("Failed starting run", ex);
            logger.WriteException(ex);
            logger.Flush();
            throw ex;
        }
}
```

Comment: can you please elaborate on this? "But this can result in the worker process to restart"

Comment: I have a support case running as we speak with Microsoft where we can see the Function App is restarted when the function throws some specific exceptions. So the worker process is destroyed. So all running functions are terminated. As you can see in the code I have updated, the throw in the catch is the source of this problem. If you have runatstartup=true you can even make a never ending loop.

Comment: if you are looking for fancy reporting OOB and retries, check out logic apps

Comment: @ThomasSegato I have the same question, sad to find this unanswered. Any chance you ever found the "right way" to do this?